# Cannot create kotlin class in itellij idea

Tags: kotlin

Cannot find the "create kotlin class" option when I right click on src inside a kotlin project in intellij idea! Doing an online course where they tell to create a kotlin class by right clicking on src but I cannot find it in the latest version

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click on the "kotlin" directory, not "src". If you used the InteliJIdea to create the project you should have a project directory structure like this

```
src -> main -> kotlin
```

Right click on Kotlin and you will see it.

Comment: Also make sure that the kotlin directory is marked as source within the module configuration dialog. Without this flag the context menu does not show the create kotlin class option

Comment: src -> main -> kotlin -> then right click -> kotlin file/class -> enter name and select file

Comment: @AnkanRay If the answer was correct and helped you, don't forget to mark the question as answered